# Odd behaviour when using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, stdin

I am new to **C** and facing an odd behavior when using malloc.

I read a input text from stdin (fgets) and pass it to a function myfunction.

```
void myfunction(char* src) {

     printf("src: |%s|\n", src);

     int srcLength = strlen(src);
     printf("src length: %d\n", srcLength);

     // CAUSES ODD BEHAVIOR IN MY SITUATION
     // char* output = malloc(200);
     //
     // if (output == NULL) {
     //   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     // }

     for (int i=0; i < srcLength; ++i) {
       char currChar = src[i];
       printf("|%c| ", currChar);
     }
}
```

When executing the function without malloc (see comment), I am getting this:

```
src: |asdf|
src length: 4
|a| |s| |d| |f|
```

But with malloc, I am getting this awkward behaviour. As if there were no chars in the char*:

```
src: |asdf|
src length: 4
|| || || ||
```

There might be an issue with the char* src (from stdin). But I am unsure because the input string is printed correctly (`src: |asdf|`).

Can anybody support me, how to analyze the source of the problem?

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the code for reading from stdin and invoking myfunction.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char *input = NULL;
  input = readStdin();
  myfunction(input);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char* readStdin(void) {
    char buffer[400];
    char *text = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    return text;
}
```

The `myfunction` and `readStdin` are in different files, but I hope it does not matter.

**UPDATE 2:**

As proposed by the supporters in the comments, I did a resolution of the scope issue.

I changed the function prototype of `readStdin` to:

```
 char* readStdin(char* input);
```

And I invoke `readStdin` with the allocated `input`.

```
 char* input = malloc(400);
```

In `readStdin` I replaced `buffer` with the function parameter.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are reading the string from stdin? What happens if you move that print of the source string to after the malloc?  Is the only difference between those outputs that you uncomment that line of code or are you changing source of your print statement?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. The `malloc()` has no apparent effect in your code but if you've corrupted the heap elsewhere even apparently harmless code can cause an underlying problem to exhibit.

Comment: What happens if the `malloc()` is done before the `printf()` of the src?  I am wondering if that still prints `src` correctly.

Comment: @pstrjds Moving the `printf("src:`  below the malloc leads to `src: ||`. I do not change anything else except for the comment. Does not sound easy to solve... I will see if I can build a minimal, full reproducible example.

Comment: So, obviously you have corrupted the heap elsewhere in your code. Please post the code where you are reading the string from stdin and where you are calling this method. As has been stated, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is src allocated?

Comment: @Bernhard_S - I would guess that if you post your `main` and this function, that would be an MCVE.  If you are new to C than I would not expect your program is very long. You could probably just post that.

Comment: @pstrjds I will post it in a second. Unfortunately the program has other functionalities too, so there is a little need to minify.

Comment: `text` : It is invalid outside function scope.

Comment: You return `text` from `readStdin`. `text` is an alias to `buffer`, which is a local variable that goes out of scope after you return from `readStdin`.

Comment: So sometimes the print does work, but it causes odd behavior?

Comment: Once you've left `readStdin`, `buffer` becomes invalid. Accessing it is _undefined behaviour_, which you should avoid. (I guess that the problem is not the `malloc`, but the additional variable `output`, which happens to occupy part of the space that was previously occupied by `buffer`, thus corrupting it.)

Comment: Is my proposed solution for the scope-issue ok (see Update 2)? It seems to work.

Comment: Yes, that will work. The only thing I would say is that you are allocating the full `400` `bytes`. This is a non-issue in your example, but consider processing numerous strings of unknown lengths (i.e. when reading from a file). Instead of allocating 400 bytes for each line, you can have an automatic buffer of size 400 that you keep re-using, and then you only allocate the memory that you need when the size of each line is known at runtime. See the example in my answer. This is totally splitting hairs, but good to think about these things while you're learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Odd behaviour when using malloc

Yes, it's odd.... or perhaps not. You code has undefined behavior so everything may happen.

The problem is that `text` will end up as a pointer to `buffer` if `fgets` is succesful. But `buffer` is a local variable in the function so as soon as `readStdin` returns the variable `buffer` doesn't exist anymore. Therefore you pass `myfunction` an invalid pointer and when you use it (i.e. for read/write), you have undefined behavior.

Once you have undefined behavior it makes no sense to reason about what is going on.... but if we try to do that anyway, a likely explanation for most systems is:

`buffer` was located on the stack. When `readStdin` returns, the stack pointer is decrement (or incremented) so that `buffer` is now on the unused part of the stack. When you call a new function, the new function will also need some stack space. How much depends on the number of variables used by the function. In other words - the more variables, the more stack space will be needed. Since the new variables will overwrite some part of the stack - and thereby overwrite parts of the memory holding the obsolete `buffer` variable - the amount of destruction of `buffer` may change with the number of variables in the function call. That is probably what you see.

But notice that the above explanation is system specific. It is not something specified by the C standard. Still, that is how most systems work.

What to do?

Instead of

```
char buffer[400];
```

do

```
char* buffer = malloc(400);
```

Comment: Thank you that works too! :) So, the `char* buffer` will exist after the `readStdin` returns, because it is a pointer to the heap and `char buffer[400]` is only local and on the stack?

Comment: @Bernhard_S Exactly.... but notice.... This is not specified by the C standard but it is how most systems works. The C standard does not mention stack and heap at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

As many have stated in the comments, you have scope issues. To avoid this, you need to allocate memory inside `readStdin()`. Quoting @MOehm from comments

> Once you've left readStdin, buffer becomes invalid. Accessing it is undefined behaviour, which you should avoid. (I guess that the problem is not the malloc, but the additional variable output, which happens to occupy part of the space that was previously occupied by buffer, thus corrupting it.)

```
#define SIZE 400

char* readStdin(void) {
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char *text = NULL

    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    text = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) + 1));//allocate memory
    strcpy(text, buffer);//and copy the buffer into it.

    int length = strlen(text);
    if (text[length - 1] == '\n') {
        text[length - 1] = '\0';
    }
    return text;
}
```

And your main function should now look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *input = NULL;
    input = readStdin();
    myfunction(input);
    free(input);//must now free it.
    input = NULL;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Try making these changes and you will see that all your problems will go away. Now `MyFunction` will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you don't get compile errors when doing `char* output = malloc(200);`: you MUST cast into `char*`, like `char* output = (char*) malloc(200);`

Comment: [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1).